# Absolute and conditional convergence of series with parameter

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I have the following series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}$$

I need to check for absolute and conditional convergence values, depending on the parameter $p$. Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Note $\sum \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges when $s > 1$.  Note $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}$ converges when $s > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{(n+1)^p}<\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}\right|<\frac{1}{(n-1)^p}.$$If you can establish these inequalities, then the rest (for absolute convergence) can be determined via the integral test for series. To check the series for conditional convergence, use the ideas above to determine what $p$ is allowed to be such that you'll still have $$\frac{1}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}\to0\quad\text{as}\quad n\to\infty.$$

Comment: For conditional convergence, this is not enough. If your goalis to use Leibniz's criterion, you need the *monotonically decreasing* part.

Comment: @ClementC.: You're mostly correct, but you don't actually need *monotonically decreasing* (I agree this is how it is generally taught, though). You just need that it doesn't oscillate *too much* (and this one doesn't).

Comment: I know the result is correct (one can also reduce it to Leibniz criterion applied to sufficiently many terms of a Taylor expansion). My point is that it may be confusing the OP into believing it works out of the box.